# My shortcut doesn't work on the watch, in production only

Tags: ios, swift, sirikit, sirishortcuts

There are a few part to this problem:

1. Running my intents extension scheme on the "Watch App" works fine. I can track the progress in the debugger, great.
2. But when I run the ap on my apple watch––simulator or real device, and not through xcode––I can't use my voice shortcuts. I get the message "sorry, there was a problem with the app" every time
3. The shortcuts work on iPhone all the time. Any iPhone, any build, from anywhere
4. Because this only happens while not debugging, it's very difficult to troubleshoot the issue

So unfortunately this is a pretty broad question: does anyone have any suspicions as to why this is? Any resources to help me troubleshoot this? I've been playing around with it for a LONG time without much success.

I've already tried a few things: switching up the schemes, iOS and watchOS versions, debug/release builds, etc. I'm beginning to think there's actually an issue with my code––my suspicion is that the shortcut is timing out––yet all the optimizations that I've made haven't amounted to any good results.

To give some background on my dev environment, I'm using Swift 4.2 and Xcode 10.1 on a Macbook running the latest version of Mojave. My test devices include a 40mm series 4 watch with watchOS 5.0 and an iPhone X running iOS 12.0.

Then there's the simulators. I've tried every version of iOS 12.* and watch 5.*

EDIT: Also, to clarify, this error occurs in the *confirmation phase* of my shortcut, not the *handle* phase.